Autodesk ACC API - Post Projects
I have seen the following post in which the migration of the POST /projects endpoint from BIM-360 to ACC is discussed. StackOverflow won't let me leave a comment on that since I don't have enough reputation yet but I would like to ask if this ACC endpoint has been finished yet or is almost finished?
Thank you

It's supported now. Please refer to this blog post:
https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/acc-project-admin-api-project-creation-and-user-management
Here is an example of calling POST projects with project template. Please refer to the tutorial for the detailed instructions.
curl -X 'POST' 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/construction/admin/v1/accounts/g5s4e3b5-vbta-6b02-d23a-5d55f36ba876/projects'
\ -H 'Authorization: Bearer AuIPTf4KYLTYGVnOHQ0cuolwCW2a'
\ -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
\ -d '{
        "name": "Project 1",
        "classification": "production",
        "startDate": "2010-01-01",
        "endDate": "2015-12-31",
        "type": "Hospital",
        "projectValue": {
            "value": 1650000,
            "currency": "USD"
        },
        "jobNumber": "HP-0002",
        "addressLine1": "123 Main Street",
        "addressLine2": "Suite 2",
        "city": "San Francisco",
        "stateOrProvince": "California",
        "postalCode": "94001",
        "country": "United States",
        "latitude": "37.773972",
        "longitude": "-122.431297",
        "timezone": "America/Los_Angeles",
        "constructionType": "New Construction",
        "deliveryMethod": "Unit Price",
        "currentPhase": "Design",
        "businessUnitId": "802a4a61-3507-4d4e-8e3c-242a31cc0549",
        "template": {
            “projectId”: "406a7b97-cb95-4331-830e-ca114a0d3cb7"
        }
    }'

